# Question about proof involving prime numbers and divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Lemma: Let $p$ be a prime number. If $p\mid m_1\cdots m_n$, then $p\mid m_i$ for some $1\le i\le n$.

I have literally no idea how to begin this problem. Any advice or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: The question is.  In your class to you know that every number, $m = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ for a *unique * set of primes and powers?  If so, were you given this as an axiom, or did you have to prove it? So each $m_i$ has a unique prime factorization.  If you take the set of all the prime factors of all $m_i$,  $p$ must be one of them so $p$ is a factor of at least one of the $m_i$.  But to say that we have to assume each number has a unique prime factorization. Are we allowed to assume that?

Answer (score 4):

Use the fact that if $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$. The lemma that you are trying to prove is the generalization!

Comment: @agra94 $(a_i,...,a_n)$ is a list of arbitrary numbers... if p divides their product than p divides one of them (or is one of them) and thus is a prime divisor of some $a_i$, also edit your question and use \cdot for multiplication

Comment: You also need to prove the fact "$p\mid ab\implies p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$".

Answer (score 0):

The well-ordering principle simply states there exists a least element.

Proof: If the list $(a_1 , ... , a_n)$ consists of composite numbers then write each composite number as a decomp of primes, let this set be $(b_1, ... , b_m)$. By the well-ordering principle the set $(b_1 , ... , b_n)$ has a least element, let this be $b_1$ if $p=b_1$ then done, if not then we can continue in this manner until we find $p$ on our list.

Alternatively as suggested above, http://www.tkiryl.com/teaching/aa/les091503.pdf use the proof from this pdf and extend it to a general case.

This is very basic number theory, some googling will go along way for these types of simple proofs.

Comment: Why would you assume p is in the list b_1, ...b_m?  Isn't that precisely what we are trying to prove?  This assumes that each a_1 has a unique prime factorization which, needs our proposition to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question and it's so fundamentally obvious that ... it's hard to figure out where to start.

Let's prove a smaller version first:  If $p$ divides $ab$ then either $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.

Proof: If $p$ divides $ab$ then $pm = ab$ for some integer $m$.  If $b$ equals $0$ we are done.  (Because $p*m = ab$ if $m$ and $b$ equal $0$.  *Everything* divides $0$).  If $b \ne 0$:

$pm = ab$ so $m/b = a/p$ are two equal fractions.

Either $a/p$ is in "lowest terms" or it isn't.  If it isn't then there is some $k$ so that $a = a'k$ and $p = p'k$ and $a/p = a'k/p'k = a'/p'$.  But $p$ is prime so if $p = p'k$ then either $k = p$ or $k= 1$.

If $k = p$ then $a = a'k = a'p$ and $p$ divides $a$ and we are done.  if $k = 1$:

then $a/p$ is in lowest terms.   And $m/b = a/p$ so there is a $k$ so that $ak = m$ and $pk = b$.  So $p$ divides $b$.  And we are done.

....

Now if $p$ divides $m_1....m_n$ then either $p$ divides $m_1$ or $p$ divides $m_2....m-n$. And if $p$ divides $m_2...m_n$ thne $p$ divides $m_2$ or $p$ divides $m_3....m_n$. And so on...

==== old answer which may have been hard to follow.====

Basically there is Euclid's lemma (google it):  That if $p$ prime divides $ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$.

If that is so then if $p|m_1.....m_n$ then $p|m_1$ or $p|m_2....m_n$.  And thus repeating inducctively $p$ must divide one of $m_1$ or $m_1$ or $m_1$ or ... $m_n$.

So we just need to prove Euclid's lemma. If $p$ is prime and $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $b$.

Let $pk = ab$ then $k/b = a/p$. ... assuming $b \ne 0$....

Either:

i) $b = 0$ and I couldn't do that.

ii) $p|a$ and $ a/p$ is an integer.

iii) $a/p$ are not in "lowest terms".

iv) $a/p$ are in lowest terms.

If i) then $p*n =b$ if $n=0$ and $b= 0$ so $p|b$.

ii) then $p|a$.

iii) then there is a $m\ne 1$ so that $a= a'*m$ and $p = p'*m$ and $a/p = a'/p'$. $p$ is prime so $m=p$ and $p' =1$ and $a = a'p$ and $p|a$.

iv) Then $k/b = a/p$ so $k/p$ is either in lowest terms and $k =a$ and $b = p$ or $k/b$ is not in lowest terms and $k = ma$ and $b=mp$ for some $m$.  Either way $p|b$.

So either $p|a$ or $p|b$.

This relies upon knowing that fractions have a "lowest  term".Which they must as if $r= m/n$ where $m,n$ are integers, $n > 0$ there must be a least $n$ where this is true.

... another proof is to use Bezouts lemma that if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ then there are integers $k,j$ so that $km + nj = 1$.  Then if $p\not \mid a$ then  $\gcd(a,p) = 1$ and there are $k,j$ so that  $ka + jp = 1$ so $kab + jpb = b$.  Let $ab = mp$ (as $p|ab$ so $kmp +jbp = b$.  So $p|b$.

But  that requires proving Bezout's Lemma.  Which can be done by a series of dividing and taking remainders.  But I don't like it for first time students.

Comment: I doubt OP will understand your answer.

Comment: Think not? I think lowest term fractions are well understood.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem. If $p$ is prime and $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b.$

Now suppose $p$ is prime and $p|m_1...m_n.$

If $n=1$ we have $p|m_1$.

If $n=2$ let $m_1=a$ and $m_2=b$ and apply the theorem.

For $n>2$ use induction on $n$: Suppose $n>2$ and that for all $m_1,...,m_{n-1}$ we have $(p|m_1...m_{n-1}\implies p|m_i$ for some $1\leq i\leq n-1.)$..... Then if $p|m_1...m_n$ let $a=m_1...m_{n-1}$ and $b=m_n.$ If $p|m_n$, we are done. If $p\not |m_n$ then $(p|ab$ and $p \not |b)$ so $p|a=m_1...m_{n-1}$ so $p|m_i$ for some $1\leq i\leq n-1.$

To prove the theorem  we will use two basic and very useful properties of $\mathbb N:\quad$ 1.Any non-empty collection of members of $\mathbb N$ has a least member....2. Any $n\in \mathbb N$  with $n>1$ is divisible by a prime.

If prime $p|ab$ and $p\not |a$ and $p\not |b,$ call $p$ an exceptional prime and call $ab$ an exceptional product for $p$.

Suppose  $p$ is the least exceptional  prime, and let $ab$ be the least positive exceptional product for $p.$ We may assume $a>0$ and $b>0.$

We must have  $a<p$ and $b<p.$ For if $a>p$ then $a=px+a'$ with positive $a',x$ but then $a'b$ is a positive exceptional product for $p$ with $a'b<ab$, which is not possible,... and a similar argument show that $b<p$.

Now $ab=pc$  with $c>1$ (because if $c=1$ then  $p =ab$ is not  prime.). So let $q$ be a prime divisor of $c$ and let $c=c'q.$ We have $$q\leq c=ab/p<p^2/p=p$$  and $p$ is the the least exceptional prime, so $q$ is not an exceptional prime. And $q|cp=ab.$ So $q|a$ or $q|b.$

If $q|a$ let $a=a'q.$ We have $$a'qb=ab=pc=pc'q$$ and therefore $a'b=pc'.$ We now have a paradox:  $p\not |b$. and $p\not |a'$ (else $p|a=a'q$) and $0<a'b <a'qb=ab,$ implying that $a'b$ is a positive exceptional product for $p$ that is smaller than the smallest positive exceptional product ($ab$) for $p.$

If $q|b ,$ a similar argument also leads to  a paradox.

So the asumption that an exceptional prime exists is untenable.